# Images Aren't Rendering in Browser - MVC3 razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, image, web

I'm trying to learn MVC3 razor but I'm hitting a snag whenever I try to display images that are stored on my local machine. The images are being displayed as an image placeholder (like below) instead of the browser rendering the image.

[placeholder image](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1430/imgplaceholder.png)

I've tried to simplify it down to just using a regular html img tag with no luck. However, everything works fine when it's pointing to an image that's hosted on the web. The path is correct because it's showing that place holder instead of a red x (which it shows when it doesn't find the image).

```
<img id="img" src="file:///C:/WebSite/Images/img1.jpg" alt="" />
```

The only thing I can think of is some sort of permissions or config that isn't set up correctly. I've set the permissions for the folders leading to the image and the image itself. My Web.config is default and the only change I've made to global.aspx is registering routes.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Trending", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Help?

Comment: you need to, if not there was a picture, the picture is displayed by default? I find it hard to understand what the problem is

Comment: include the image folder in your project

Comment: @simplydenis - The actual image is not appearing in the browser. Instead, a default image place holder is appearing like the one in the link that I posted. When I change the path to be incorrect, a red X appears so it seems like it is finding the image. It's just not displaying it for some reason.

Comment: @COLDTOLD - I believe it is included. The folder and image are in the project and I have built and published it before I view the site. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: just drag the image from the folder to the file

Comment: @COLDTOLD - I had already done that. I tried deleting all the published files and re-published from scratch. Everything was in the right place but still got that placeholder image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Url.Content helper, assuming your Images folder is at the root of your application it would be something like :

```
<img id="img" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/img1.jpg")" alt="" />
```

Comment: Well, I went back and tried using Url.Content again... And it worked =). When I was originally trying it, I had the pictures in a folder that was inside the App_Data folder. That seems to block access to the images even though the path was correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Dom how does this exactly work? I have my images in a folder called 'UploaderHoldings' in my Local Drive C: but I even using your solution it didnt show the img.